# Sampling "Random" Cyclic / Acyclic Graphs

Tags: graphs-and-networks, random

This is an extension of [RandomGraph with specific constraints](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/84338/randomgraph-with-specific-constraints)

Where @Histograms wanted to make $n$ random graphs with a specific constraint (in @Histogram's case, having 2 vertices each with exactly one edge).

My question is if there is a way to sample $n$ random graphs with the following constraints:

- all graphs have exactly $v$ vertices
- generated graphs are either acyclic / cyclic depending on a boolean
- if it simplifies the problem, then either only directed / undirected

As I only care about if there are exactly $v$ vertices (all graphs have the same dimension for their adjacency matrix), the graphs can have any number of edges. Likewise, since these are represented as adjacency matrices, multi-edges are filtered out. Although buckles are still feasible...

For example, suppose I want to sample (randomly) $50$ acyclic graphs with $10$ vertices and $50$ cyclic graphs with $10$ vertices.

One can produce $n$ `RandomGraph`s with fixed number of vertices from a distribution from:

```
RandomGraph[BernoulliGraphDistribution[numVertices, probOfEdge], numGraphs]
```

However, even with large $n$, these graphs tend to favor one state for these boolean properties of graphs.

Currently I think one could use `RandomTree` to produce both acyclic *and* cyclic graphs, where a tree is acyclic by nature, and adding an edge to a random number of leaves to the root of the tree would produce "random" cyclic graphs. However manipulating vertices in the Graph object returned by `Combinatorica` is a bit lost to me.

Thoughts?

Comment: Graphs cannot be truly "random" if there are specified constraints, e.g., planarity...

Comment: @DavidG.Stork true, but you can randomly sample the space of all graphs which match that constraint

Comment: OK.  Fair enough.

Comment: This is way too broad.  Entire mathematical papers are written about how to do it for just a single property.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork What you say makes no sense to me (or at least severely distorts the usual meaning of "random"). We have a set of elements. A subset satisfies a condition.  We can sample uniformly from this subset.  BTW there are many papers on the uniform sampling of planar graphs (just google).

Comment: The only truly general method to do it is to sample all graphs, then reject those that do not satisfy your property. This, however, is often not practical at all because you will end up rejecting the vast majority of samples. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rejection_sampling  If you can restrict your question to one specific problem, then it would be acceptable. Otherwise I'm afraid it would get closed.

Comment: @Szabolcs agreed, too broad. I was hoping that there would be a solution which did not require producing all and filtering. I narrowed it down to acyclic / cyclic

Comment: Do you need directed or undirected?  Connected only or also unconnected?  Uniform sampling of directed acyclic graphs with a given number of edges is easy:  fill out a random selection of adjacency matrix elements above the diagonal. Implementation: `DirectedGraph[RandomGraph[{n,m}], "Acyclic"]`.

Comment: If you want directed and *connected* ones, then you need trees as you said. Uniform sampling of trees on $n$ vertices is implemented in IGraph/M through `IGTreeGame` (I contributed this recently to the core igraph library).  If we allow unconnected, that would require some more thought to ensure that the sampling will be uniform.  So I'll wait until you clarify the question.

Comment: If you want directed *and* connected, that might be the hardest of all. Please also state if you have any constraint on the number of edges (e.g. fixed). Even seemingly small changes to the constraints can make a big difference to the difficulty of the problem.

Comment: @Szabolcs question updated providing more info. The main concern is having two equal populations (cyclic / acyclic) graphs where all adjacency matrices are the same size (having $n$ vertices). Thus, connected-ness between components is not really a requirement. Likewise, any number of edges is fine so long as I can get $n$ cyclic and $n$ acyclic graphs. Directed / undirected is also - for this application - not really important, so whatever is easier to generate.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have not specified in the question as to what "random" means exactly, let us proceed along the lines you suggest. That is, to get an acyclic graph we sample a tree (but not necessarily uniformly at random from the set of all $n$-vertex trees), and for cyclic graphs we can take a [pseudotree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudoforest).

```
    RandomTree[n_] := Graph@Table[i <-> RandomInteger[{0, i - 1}], {i, 1, n}];

    RandomPseudotree[n_] := Module[{g = RandomTree[n]},
    u = First[RandomSample[VertexList[g], 1]];
    v = First[RandomSample[
     Complement[Complement[VertexList[g], {u}], 
     AdjacencyList[g, u]], 1]];
    EdgeAdd[g, UndirectedEdge[u, v]]
  ]
```

Afterwards, the generation is straightforward:

```
Join[Table[RandomTree[10], {2}], Table[RandomPseudotree[10], {2}]]
```

As is evident, after we have a way of constructing a tree, a pseudotree is formed by sampling two vertices with an edge added between them. Here we only have to be careful not to sample two adjacent vertices, i.e., ensure that the cycle we put in is of length at least three.